# Is a homeomorphism which maps lines to lines (and fixes zero) necessarily linear?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology

We know the homeomorphism $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ maps straight lines to straight lines and the zero vector to the zero vector. Is it Linear?? If so, how can we prove it?

Comment: I've changed the tags a bit. "soft-question" and "recreational-mathematics" don't seem to be a good fit. In turn, I've added the "real-analysis" tag. I've also added a more informative title. The old title, while attention grabbing, does not provide problem context.

Comment: When you mean straight lines to straight lines, do you mean any line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or only lines passing through the origin?

Comment: I checked mathoverflow. Your question was discussed and answered there: mathoverflow.net/questions/123356

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asuming $n>1$? If not a good counter-example could be the function $\phi(x)=x^3$ ( $x\in\mathbb{R}$) . It's a homeomorphism, maps $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (the only line in $\mathbb{R}$) and obviously it maps $0$ to $0$

Comment: The same way, it could be done in any dimension: $φ(x) = ||x||^2 x$, $x ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @user87690 This preserves straight lines through the origin, but not all straight lines in $\mathbb R^n$. Consider, e.g., the points $(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)\in\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @WillG Yes, you are right.

Answer (score -3):

This is not enough to suggest linearity w/o it being a homeomorphism... It has satisfy $\phi(a*v_1 + b*v_2) = a\phi(v_1)+b\phi(v_2)$.  So lines to lines does not promise linearity, though it is a requirement as lines are a linear combination of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Assuming you are looking at $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a combination of vectors in the typical sense.

The homeomorphism takes away the discontinuous cases and the situations with a kernel.  My bad I did not read the problem correctly initially.

Lines can be expressed as a linear combination of elements in a vector space with an indeterminate to the first power.  Just express a matrix with such a basis as the mapping and you have you linearity in the form of a matrix.

Comment: Why is mapping lines to lines an insufficient requirement for linearity? Did you have a specific counter-example in mind? As it stands, your answer right now simply states the definition of linearity.