# Do these conditions characterize Lorentz transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, mathematical-physics, projective-geometry, affine-geometry

Let $M=\mathbb R^4$ with the symmetric bilinear form $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ defined by $\langle(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3),(y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3)\rangle=x_0y_0-x_1y_1-x_2y_2-x_3y_3$. Let $T:\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R^4$ be a map satisfying the following conditions.

1. $T$ is a bijection
2. $T(0)=0$
3. $\langle x,y\rangle=0\implies\langle Tx,Ty\rangle=0$
4. $T$ maps inertial worldlines to inertial worldlines.

In (4), an **inertial worldline** is a set of the form $(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)+\mathbb R(1,v_x,v_y,v_z),$ where $v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2<1$. (If the first coordinate is thought of as time, then these are straight lines through $M$ representing particles moving at a constant velocity less than the speed of light, in units where $c=1.)$

A **Lorentz transformation** is a linear map on $M$ preserving $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ between all points. Must $T$ be a Lorentz transformation? Please give a proof, if yes, or a counterexample, if no.

---

[There](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480550/function-that-maps-straight-lines-into-straight-lines) [are](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944016/a-question-about-linear-transformations-mapping-straight-lines-to-straight-lines) [lots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480380/is-a-homeomorphism-which-maps-lines-to-lines-and-fixes-zero-necessarily-linear) [of](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107648/non-linear-function-on-mathbbr2-preserving-the-origin-and-maps-lines-onto) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035208/is-a-map-that-preserves-lines-and-fixes-the-origin-necessarily-linear) [asking](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035287/is-a-function-which-preserves-zero-and-affine-lines-necessarily-linear?noredirect=1&lq=1) [about](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035208/is-a-map-that-preserves-lines-and-fixes-the-origin-necessarily-linear?noredirect=1&lq=1) [whether](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3985327/is-lines-remain-lines-sufficient-to-characterise-linearity-in-mathbb-r2?noredirect=1&lq=1) maps from $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ preserving straight must be linear. The answer seems to be "yes" if the map is injective and $n\geqslant2$, but the result seems to be difficult to prove, and related to something called the fundamental theorems of affine/projective geometry.

This question, alternatively, considers only lines whose "slope" is bounded by $1$, along with some other conditions motivated by special relativity.

Comment: There's definitely something wrong with the definition of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. Aside from the obvious typos, it doesn't seem to be bilinear at all.

Comment: @TedShifrin Whoops, I fixed it (I hope).

Comment: Much better :) So the serious question is whether $T$ is forced to be linear.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think that's the harder part, but I still don't see how preservation of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ follows quickly from linearity, if that's what you're implying.